# Case Feed and default email template assignment

Tags: apex, email, class

Is there a way in which to assign a particular email template ID to the Case Feed?

Answer (score 1):

From the Salesforce Help page [Enable Default Email Templates in Case Feed](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=case_interaction_default_templates.htm&language=en_US),

> Before you can enable default email templates, you need to create text, HTML, or Visualforce templates, and create an Apex class that contains template selection logic.
>
> To enable default email templates:
>
> 1. From Setup, click Customize | Cases | Support Settings.
> 2. Click Edit.
> 3. Select Enable default email templates.
> 4. Choose the Apex class that contains your template selection logic.
> 5. Click Save.